# How to avoid html and body element from displaying while inspecting elements?

Tags: html, css

I can't properly inspect the elements inside the red background because when I hover outside the red background the body and html elements keeps showing, how to avoid that?

[image]
[image]

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: royalblue;
    font-family: monospace;
}

header {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.nav {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

.nav li {
    margin: -3px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 7px 3px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
}

.nav a {
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 50px;
    font-size: 15px; 
}
```

```html
<body>  
     <header>
        <ul class="nav">     
            <li><a href="homepage.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li id="log"><a href="index.html">Login</a></li>             </ul>     
     </header> 
</body>
```

Comment: This seems like more of an Apple Developer Tools problem?

Comment: *ERROR from SO because you have added to much code in question & very less explanation. *

Comment: Can you check the same in Chrome browser?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the element to inspect in the outline you see in the inspector. Press the "▶" next to ... to expand it and browse for the element of your choice.